# How to increase performance of dynamic textures on many sprites in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have many sprites. Think thousands of sprites that have different textures. 
https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_sprites.html
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/SpriteMaterial

Now my scene animates, I want to change the text content of these sprites. I do so by setting on each frame:

```
var animate = function() {
   requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    for (var sprite in sprites) {
       newText = randomText(); // think some uniquely random text or number on each frame
       sprite.material.map = changeText(newText);
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

and changeText looks something like this:

```
function changeText(newText) {
     var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
     var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
     canvas.width = 40; canvas.height = 40;
     // ... set color etc
     ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 40, 40);
     // ... set another color then
     context.fillText(newText, 0, 0);

     var amap = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
    amap.needsUpdate = true;

    return amap;
}
```

Now this works but it absolutely crawls if I do this on each frame as opposed to doing it once. Maybe createElement is expensive. When I try to set the canvas as a global variable for some reason it makes the sprites all have the same texture even though I'm redrawing the canvas for each symbol. Regardless, it's still very slow so I didn't investigate further.

I also noticed that if I pregenerate all the texts before hand and then just use a hashmap to assign them then it works fast and good. So it's just the texture generation (in changeText()) that is making this slow. But I need the texture to be completely dynamic so I can't generate all the texts beforehand. Any ideas?

Comment: Creating small canvas elements on-the-fly is expensive, as you have already noticed. You should re-use the canvas element and obviously clear it before using it. You should also create one larger canvas instead of several small ones and use it as a sprite. For example: 400x400 canvas will be equivalent to a hundred 40x40 canvases and 4000x4000 canvas will be equivalent to ten thousand 40x40 canvases. Dimension it according to your needs.

Comment: Uploading textures to the GPU is a bottleneck. That's why realtime game engines always load all the textures they're going to use at the beginning (loading screen) and then they maintain the same textures stored in the VRAM throughout the gameplay. I think the spritesheet mentioned above is the way to go, but you'll need to write custom shaders. You can look at the [spritesheet example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=sprite#webgl_sprites_nodes), it only uses [this single image](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/textures/WalkingManSpriteSheet.png) to animate.

Comment: I'm currently thinking of just creating textures of 0 through 9 and then creating a number by positioning multiples of these textures together based on whatever the changing number is.

Comment: Manually stitching numbers together probably won't look nice due to poor letter spacing. But if you only have numbers, then you could have a spacing lookup table for all of the combinations of adjacent numbers.